# Use Adafruit PiTFT as hat with Adafruit DS3231 in a case

Tags: hat, pitft, case, adafruit

I have a raspberry pi 3 A+ connected to an [Adafruit PiTFT Plus 320x240 2.8" TFT + Capacitive Touchscreen](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2423) and an [Adafruit DS3231 Precision RTC Breakout](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3013) for keeping time.  Both are connected using jumper cables, and both work as expected.

I want to be able to use a case like this: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2363 and https://www.adafruit.com/product/2808
[image: Faceplate and Buttons Pack for 2.4" PiTFT HAT - Raspberry Pi A+]

The problem is that when it's in the case, the screen connects to the pi as a hat, not with jumper cables.  This blocks the rest of the IO pins, so I can't connect the DS3231 to the pi.

Is there a way to still connect it?  (To be clear, I am not trying to get the DS3231 to fit inside the case.  I just want the screen and pi in the case, the DS3231 can stick out using jumper cables.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Adafruit designed it without pins you would need to solder to the bottom of the pins on the Pi.

The site says "This version also has all 40 pins GPIO pins brought out so you can connect a 40-pin GPIO cable underneath".